# rworldmap-map-doesn't appear in knit (html)

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, knitr, rworldmap

> Hi. 
>   I am using "rworldmap" package for my data. Everything performs well, the only problem is related to kniting the html format. The html output doesn't show the map . I have other graphs in the html output. They graph (map) that wasn't there is rworldmap.
>
> Note:
>
> 1- I need to upload my data as a html file.
>
> 2- I am using library(rworldmap) due to the my data.

## I don't know why the knit (html) doesn't show the map in my file. Any suggestion?

## Format of my html file:

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    code_folding: show
    toc_float: 
        collapsed: false
        smooth_scroll: true
    number_sections: true
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default
---
```

## Start:

```
library(rworldmap)
str(data)

 Country: chr  "ALBANIA" "ALBANIA" "ALBANIA" "ALBANIA" 
 var1: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 var2: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
 var3: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Table:

```
Country   var1   var2   var3   n   Perc
ALBANIA     1      1      1    1   0.075
TURKEY      1      1      1    18   1.35
GERMANY     1      1      0    3    0.22
...
```

> n is the frequency

## rworldmap Code:

```
dev.new(width=20, height=20)
summary_probn<-count(data, Country, 
var1,var3, 
var2)
diss_c<- subset(summary_probn, var1 =="1")
#table<-table(diss_c)#frequency
#proptable<- prop.table(table(diss_c))#Cumulative frequency
#cbind(table, proptable)
diss_c$Perc <- diss_c$n / sum(diss_c$n) * 100
diss_cc<- subset(diss_c, var1 =="1") 
diss_cj <- subset(diss_cc, var2 =="1")
```

## The data is like the following output:

## Map

```
mapped_data2 <- joinCountryData2Map(diss_cj, joinCode = "NAME", 
nameJoinColumn = "Country")
par(mai=c(1,0,0.8,2),xaxs="i",yaxs="i")
mapParams <- mapCountryData(mapped_data2, nameColumnToPlot = "Perc", 
catMethod="fixedWidth",  addLegend=FALSE, mapTitle="Europe", mapRegion = "europe")
do.call(addMapLegend ,c(mapParams ,legendLabels="all",legendWidth=1,legendIntervals="data", legendMar = 3, labelFontSize = 1))
#do.call( addMapLegend, c(mapParams, legendWidth=1.5, legendMar = 2, legendLabels="all"))
colourPalette <- c('white','green','red','yellow','blue','black')
```

Comment: could you provide your full rmd source file and html output (in a github repo maybe)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this question. I defined this feature in my rmarkdown file: "dev.new(width=20, height=20)". 
When I removed it, "rworldmap output" appeared in html file.